# Handling subscribe in service and not component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-http

I have a simple setup in Angular to see how I can retrieve my data from a remote server. The sample project that I made has a component : ServerCompoent

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-server',
        templateUrl: './server.component.html'
    })
    export class ServerComponent {
        constructor(private serverService: ServerService){}

        displayServers() {
               this.serverService.getServers().subscribe(
                   (response)=> console.log(response),
                   (error) => console.log(error)
        }
```

and a service that fetch data from my back-end called: ServerService

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerService{

     constructor (private http: Http) {}
     // private instance variable to hold base url
     private serverUrl= 'http://localhost:8080/server';

    getServer(){
       return this.http.get(this.serverUrl);
    }
  );
}
```

So for now, everything works like a charm, but is it possible to subscribe to the observable returned in the service and not the component. I think that having .subscribe code part is not really clean. Is there a way to achieve such behavior know that the DI in Angular is Synchronous?

Thank you

Comment: You want to make an asynchronous function synchronous?

Comment: The consumer of the data has to subscribe, therefore subscribing in the component is "clean".

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe in the service instead of the component, but this doesn't make this synchronous. Observable is asynchronous in nature.

Comment: The problem is that when I do the subscribe method in the service and try to return the data to the component. I don't get the information. Seems like that since the request to the server take some time to be done, he returns nothing to the component and once the result are retrieved in the service, I can show it on the console, but the value in the component didn't update